# Integrating Apache Drill with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-drill, bigdata

I'm new to Apache Drill. How to integrate Apache Drill with Spark? I'm unable find any resourceful link except the below
https://drill.apache.org/blog/2014/12/16/whats-coming-in-2015/

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.